# @Value for numeric types in yaml file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I got a `data.yml` in resources folder of a following structure:

```
main:
  header:
    info: 3600L
```

I use Spring Boot version 2.4.2, I want to inject property `main.header1.info` to a field, I do this the following way:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:data.yml")
public class SomeClass {
    @Value("`main.header1.info")
    private long info;
    ...
}
```

But a `NumberFormatException` ocurres:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "main.header1.info"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:692) ~[na:na]
    ...
```

I know that `long` is not supported in `yml`, but I think its not the case. I tried other numeric types and corresponding wrapper-classes, like `Double`.
So, how to fix that?

Comment: Try `@Value("${main.header.info}")`.

Comment: Also, if you're using Boot you should be using `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Comment: `@Value("${...}")` doesn't work. The problem is that `@PropertySource("...")` doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `application.yml` file inspite of custom `YAML` file.

> *Reason* : `application.properties` is spring's default config file. If you use it, you don't have to worry about loading the file to
> context manually as spring takes care of it. But, In you case, you are
> trying to load and read value from a custom YAML file. So,
> `@PropertySource` won't help here.

Refer to the [spring-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings) for details about YAML Shortcomings.

However if you still wish to read values from a custom yaml, You will need to write a custom class ( Ex : `CustomYamlPropertySourceFactory` ) which implements `PropertySourceFactory` & inform `@PropertySource` to use this factory class.

**Reference Code :**

```
    @Component
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:date.yml", factory = CustomYamlPropertySourceFactory.class) 
    public class SomeClass {

    @Value("${main.header.info}")
    private int info;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `${main.header.info}` to inject the value from properties.
`@PropertySource` doesn't support the loading of `.yaml` or `yml` files.
Try to use `.properties` file for loading them using `@PropertySource`.

> There was an issue opened for this but Spring guys closed it. Many
> developers opposed and were unhappy with this. They still demanded to
> re-open this issue.

- Read here : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18486
- Read [M. Deinum Article](https://deinum.biz/2018-07-04-PropertySource-with-yaml-files/) for a workaround of this problem to load YML files using `@PropertySource`.

Instead create `data.properties` file.

```
main.header.info=3600L
```

Modify the code to this :

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:data.properties")
public class SomeClass {
    @Value("${main.header1.info}")
    private long info;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**For those out there who due to constraints cannot use an `application.properties` files and need the properties provided as a `YAML` file:**

As many answers say here, there is no default way for Spring to parse `YAML` property files. The default `DefaultPropertySourceFactory` implementation is only capable of parsing `.properties` and `.xml` files.

You need to create a custom factory class implementing `PropertySourceFactory` to let the framework know how to parse a specific configuration source.

Here is a basic example on how to do that:

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactoryExample implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(final String name, final EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        final Properties propertiesFromYaml = loadYamlIntoProperties(resource);
        final String sourceName = name != null ? name : resource.getResource().getFilename();
        return new PropertiesPropertySource(sourceName, propertiesFromYaml);
    }

    private Properties loadYamlIntoProperties(final EncodedResource resource) {

        final YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(resource.getResource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }
}
```

With it you are accomplishing two things:

- Loading the `YAML` configurations into a `Properties` object.
- Returning a `PropertiesPropertySource` object which wraps the loaded `Properties`.

After that you can reference it in a `factories` atribute of any `@PropertyResource`:

```
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:path/to/your/properties.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactoryExample.class)
```

---

Edit: It cannot be used with `@TestPropertySource`, it does not support any `factories` at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a yml file with `@PropertySource`.

> YAML files cannot be loaded by using the `@PropertySource` annotation. So, in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use a properties file.

See [YAML Shortcomings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings) documentation.